# Entity Framework 6 Automatic Migrations Rebuilds Tables Periodically on Production Server

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

After re-deploying my project to the production server daily it rebuilds two tables in the database (BatchImportDatas and BatchImportLogs), deleting all data in those tables.  However, this does not happen on my dev database and only occurs on two tables though many other tables in the application are also managed by the EF 6 auto migration. Since I am using the auto migration no migration files are generated in the migration folder of the application, however I am certain the EF migrations are the culprit because a migration entry is entered in the _MigrationHistory table when this occurs. I have deleted all relevant records in the _MigrationHistory table and forced a rebuild of the effected DB tables but that did not rectify this issue.  I do not want to delete all the migration records and rebuild the entire production database because portions of the application are in use and other tables in the db contain live data.  Below are the EF configuration details for my project. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Migration Configuration file:

```
namespace SYSTEM_Base.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class newDb_Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SYSTEM_Base.Entities.Commissions.CommissionsBase_New>
    {
        public newDb_Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(SYSTEM_Base.Entities.Commissions.CommissionsBase_New context)
        {
            //context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('BatchImportLogs', RESEED, 1000);");
        }
    }
}
```

DbContext (Database core config):

```
using SYSTEM_Base.Migrations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Providers.Entities;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace SYSTEM_Base.Entities.Commissions
{
        public class CommissionsBase_New : DbContext
        {
            public CommissionsBase_New() : base("SYSTEM") { }

            public DbSet<MembershipAddProperty> MembershipAddProperties { get; set; }

            public DbSet<AppSetting> AppSettings { get; set; }

            public DbSet<ReportRoleLevel> ReportRoleLevels { get; set; }

            public DbSet<ResetPasswordRequest> ResetPasswordRequests { get; set; }

            public DbSet<BatchImportData> BatchImportData { get; set; }

            public DbSet<BatchImportLog> BatchImportLog { get; set; }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
            {
                Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<CommissionsBase_New, newDb_Configuration>());
            }
        }
}
```

Last 10 _MigrationHistory records in Dev Database:

[image: Last 10 _MigrationHistory records in Dev Database:]

Last 10 _MigrationHistory records in Production Database:

[image: Last 10 _MigrationHistory records in Production Database:]

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple instances of your production code using different versions of your defined EF context. If that is the case, ensure the DLL that contains your migration scripts are all running against the same version. Otherwise you'll run into the scenario you describe where the database schema is constantly upgraded/downgraded

Comment: To correct my comment, instead of "...that contains your migration scripts..." should read "...that contains your defined EF Context..." since you are not explicitly creating migration scripts.

Comment: Currently, the DLL that contains my defined EF Context is the same version on both the dev and production servers.  However for a while the versions differed because I did not want to deploy the new function (which uses the two tables in question) till I had roughly completed the code. Currently the last version of both _MigrationHistory tables is 6.0.0-20911, but it appears the production database periodically upgrades to 6.1.3-40302.  How could I stop that from occurring?

Comment: Could you post the last 10 or so results from your migration history table?

Comment: @bman7716 - Please see the screen shots I added to my original post. Could I restore the _MigrationHistory table of the dev database to the production DB or would that cause a complete rebuild of the production DB?

Comment: The version you mentioned isn't the version of your assembly that contains your `CommissionsBase_New` and/or your `newDb_Configuration`, but the EntityFramework.dll version. From your logs it is clear there are 2 versions of your application running in production, which means you likely have 2 (or more) different versions of your generated assembly that contains your `CommissionsBase_New` and/or `newDb_Configuration`.

Comment: I'm afraid that restoring  your migration history table from production to dev isn't going to get you anywhere. All you'll end up with is a possible migration being executed again on your dev database. The question isn't _why_ it's being logged to the migration table this way, but _who/what_ is executing the migration.

Comment: @bman7716 - Fixed it! Thanks for your help. You were correct two different assembly versions were running causing this issue. There is an asp.net component to the application which the winform application accesses some functions of.  I hadn't redeployed the asp.net application's assemblies because I hadn't built anything in that portion in a long time, however the .dll of the asp.net application had been rebuilt on my dev machine, thus causing the issue. I deployed the current build of the asp.net application and I think all is good now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have multiple instances of your production code using different versions of your defined EF context. If that is the case, ensure the DLL that contains your migration scripts are all running against the same version. Otherwise you'll run into the scenario you describe where the database schema is constantly upgraded/downgraded

The version you mentioned isn't the version of your assembly that contains your `CommissionsBase_New` and/or your `newDb_Configuration`, but the `EntityFramework.dll` version.

From your logs it is clear there are 2 versions of your application running in production, which means you likely have 2 (or more) different versions of your generated assembly that contains your `CommissionsBase_New` and/or `newDb_Configuration`